# Issues with writing a new flowfile in ExecuteScript NiFi

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am trying to use ExecuteScript processor to execute a piece of java code to filter the csv file and output a new csv file.

It will occur an error: transfer relationship not specified. How can I fix that?

My code:

```
FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
    if (flowFile == null) {
      return;
    }
FlowFile newflowFile = session.create();

try {
Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(flowFile), StandardCharsets.UTF-8);
Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(newflowFile), StandardCharsets.UTF-8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
CSVPrinter printer = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.print(writer);

...
//using printer write a new content

session.transfer(newflowFile, REL_SUCCESS);

} catch (Exception e) {

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: You have to do something with all flowfiles you are getting or creating.

Comment: Paths.get(newflowFile) looks incorrect

Comment: @daggett Paths.get(flowFile)  FlowFile outFile = session.write(session.create(), out -> out.write(flowFile));  Can I do this? Writer will cover the old flowfile, then create a new flowfile.

Comment: no. nothing to do with Paths in nifi...
by your question it sounds like you want to override content of existing flow file - right?

Comment: @daggett Yes,correct. How to do that? Do I need to use outputStream to overide the original flowfile?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use ExecuteGroovyScript instead of ExecuteScript - it has more features and it does compilation on processor init once. so, it's a bit faster.

here is a base for the script if you plan to read and write data from/to the same flow file.

```
def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

ff.write{InputStream rawIn, OutputStream rawOut->
    //rawIn - current flowfile content
    //rawOut - stream for a new flowfile content
    rawIn.withReader("UTF-8"){reader->
        rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){writer->
            CSVPrinter printer = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.print(writer)
            ...
        }
    }
}

REL_SUCCESS << ff  //the same as session.transfer
```